# Correctness with/without induction

Tags: induction, recursion

I am a developer who tries to improve himself in algorithm design fields, and I got stuck in a problem. The mission is to prove the correctness of the following algorithm:

For all integer constants c>=2:

```
function multiple(y, z)
    // comment: Return the product yz
    if (z == 0) return 0;
    return multiple(c*y, floor(z / c)) + y * (z % c);
```

Now what I got is for cases:

```
1. z == c => c * y * (1 % c) => z * y * 1
2. z < c  => y * (z % c) => y * z
```

I got stuck when z > c. I couldn't find a general calculation for this state (I followed the recursion for some cases, but it didn't get me any closer to the general case).

[The question taken from `The Algorithm Design Manual - second edition, by Steven S. Skiena`]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you want to use strong induction.  That is, you want to prove $f(p, q) = p \cdot q$ given the assumptions that $\forall r < q : f(p, r) = p \cdot r$

Because this isn't regular induction, your two cases aren't going to be "base case" and "inductive case".  You'll instead use the definition of $f$ to turn $f(p, q) = p \cdot q$ into the two algorithmic cases, $q = 0$ and $q \ne 0$.

So you need to prove $$\forall r < q : f(p, r) = p \cdot r \vdash f(p, 0) = p \cdot 0$$
and
$$\forall r < q : f(p, r) = p \cdot r \vdash f\left(c\cdot p, \left\lfloor \frac q c \right\rfloor\right) + p \cdot (q ~\%~ c) = p \cdot q$$

The first case is straightforward.  For the second case, use the inductive assumption to turn $f\left(c\cdot p, \left\lfloor \frac q c \right\rfloor\right)$ into a multiplication (because $\left\lfloor \frac q c \right\rfloor < q$) and use the theorem $a = \left \lfloor \frac ab \right \rfloor \cdot b + (a ~\% ~b)$.

Comment: I am having a hard time with the theorem you mentioned. I can see that it almost what we have here, but it's not exactly the same. Here I got: `y * (c * (floor(z / c) % c) + z % c)`, and I can't prove that the inner expression is equal to z.

Comment: @KorelK You made a mistake, there is no %c after the floor(z/c).

Comment: `multiply(cy, floor(z/c)) + y · (z mod c)` => `cy * (floor(z/c) % c) + y * (z % c)` => `y * (c * (floor(z/c) % c) + z % c)` What am I missing?

Comment: The inductive assumption is that $\text{multiply}(cy, \lfloor z / c \rfloor) = cy \cdot \lfloor z/c \rfloor$.  No idea where you are getting that %c from.

Comment: You are right, but I can't make this assumption if I can't prove it first, am I wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the concept of mathematical induction.

Comment: @KorelK Roughly speaking, the way strong induction works, is that you establish multiply(y,z)=z assuming multiply(cy,⌊z/c⌋)=cy⋅⌊z/c⌋ , and you establish multiply(cy,⌊z/c⌋)=cy⋅⌊z/c⌋ assuming multiply(ccy,⌊⌊z/c⌋/c⌋)=ccy⋅⌊⌊z/c⌋/c⌋, and you establish multiply(ccy,⌊⌊z/c⌋/c⌋)=ccy⋅⌊⌊z/c⌋/c⌋ assuming you know what.  Eventually you will reach the zero case which doesn't assume anything.  Ofc, you don't actually do that all separately, just establishing one of those is sufficient to establish all of them.

Comment: So if I take the case I ,mentioned in the question, when `z < c`, and I take the case when `z = 0`, I actually can say that I proved it?

Comment: @KorelK A person who understands induction could say that they proved it.  But I think you need to study weak and strong induction before you let yourself off the hook like that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=qc+r$

$\lfloor \frac{z}{c} \rfloor=q$,

$z\equiv r \pmod c$

Given $2$ integers $y,z$ the algorithm in order to compute $M(y,z)$ computes the following

$$M(cy,q)  + ry$$

which is true since $z=qc+r$ and $yz=qyc+ry$

Another way to look at this is,

Lets say there are $2$ numbers $17$ and $15$
In order to compute $M(17,15)$ , the algorithm breaks $15$, which is your $z$ in to smaller parts namely a multiple of $c$ and a leftover part which would be $z\equiv r \pmod c$ in this case.

Now, each product can be found separately, the algorithm continues to break up the multiplication into even smaller steps.

Comment: I can't understand the `r` you used in your answer.

Comment: @KorelK Given some integer $c$, every integer $z$ can be uniquely represented as $z=qc + r$ where $0 \le r < c$  For example given $c = 20$, you can represent $55$ as $55 = 2 \cdot 20 + 15$ and that is the only way to do it.  $0 \le 15 < 20$.

Comment: I see, and what does this mean: ` ≡  (mod )`?

Comment: $r$ is the remainder when $z$ is divided by $c$. Example: $7\equiv 1\pmod 3$

Comment: $713 \equiv 13 \pmod { 100 }$ It means instead of treating all integers as distinct, we'll say they are the same, modulo p, if they have the same remainder when divided by p.